# IOS catalyst can't get products in Catalina system, it is always in the request state

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, macos-catalina, mac-catalyst

in-app-purchase. IOS catalyst can't get products in Catalina system, it is always in the request state. But it's normal in IOS and bigsur 。

Answer (score 0):

1.This is my solution. (supplement: MRC managed memory)

Delay releasing the skproductsrequest object. Let it be released in the dealloc method.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CreRe.png)

2. This is a solution to similar problems encountered by netizens
   I hadn't made a strong reference to the SKProductsRequest. This didnt' cause an issue with all my iOS apps but failed with the macOS version. I just put " var request: SKProductsRequest! " and now the macOS catalyst app finds the iap product details fine now.